# (Done) Can we reopen the zhuzh question?

Tags: support, reopen-request

This question [Work place appearance - zhuzh it up a bit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/185928/work-place-appearance-zhuzh-it-up-a-bit) *was* unclear. And VtCs came it. And then the OP answered the questions for clarification and *did* provide her country and workplace circumstances.

I don't think it's unclear any more. If it is, it has no active, unanswered comments asking for clarification, which would certainly make it hard for the OP to "clarify" anything she wasn't asked for.

Can we reopen it? If not, can we at least *ask for clarification*?

I don't think there is any action *for the OP* to get this question reopened in this state. It's up to us.

I also don't get the 4 downvotes, but at least that is not keeping her from getting help here.

Comment: The OP has addressed the comments after closure and it looks clear enough to me now. Not the best question but doesn't fit the closure reason anymore. I'll make a judgement call on it

Comment: @Kilisi Actually, when the OP clarified the open points, the question was still at 4 close votes when I edited in their info. So someone else must have felt it was unclear... or more likely felt the need to push the question over the threshold without actually looking at it.

Comment: The effed up thing with the SE model of doing this (and this is certainly not specific to this site or question) is that as far as I know, votes aren't shown. So for the OP, the timeline now is: asked question => was asked for clarification => provided clarification => question was closed as unclear. That timeline is just weird for anyone not looking behind the scenes.

Comment: Good thing you're watching then, or it would still be closed. I looked at it a bit earlier and wondered why it was closed, but wouldn't have reopened without someone elses input.